# SQL Server - Generate 6 float values that MAX - MIN = parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate 6 float values with 1 decimal in the best way and performance possible where:

```
MAX(value) - MIN(value) = @parameter
```

I have this code:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @parameter float = 0.6      

    WHILE @validated = 0
        BEGIN

            IF @count < 6
            BEGIN -- fill table with 6 random values from 0 to 2 (with 1 decimal)
                INSERT INTO @tempdata ([value])
                SELECT ROUND(RAND()*(2-0),1);
                SET @count = @count + 1
            END



            IF @count = 6 -- if temp table has 6 values then do the validation
            BEGIN
                SELECT @result = (MAX(value) - MIN(value)) FROM @tempdata
                IF(@result = @parameter)
                BEGIN
                    PRINT 'MATCH PARAMETER'

                    SET @validated = 1
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    DELETE @tempdata
                    SET @counter = 0
                END
            END

        END
   END
```

This is working but sometimes it takes 10 or 20 seconds and should be faster.

For example if @`parameter` value is: **0.8** then we need **6** numbers between **0** and **2** where the MAX - MIN match that, for example:

```
    0.7    
    1.1
    0.6
    0.9
    1.5
    1.2

MAX(1.5) - MIN(0.7) = 0.8
```

> Any clue?

Comment: . . Why not just use equally spaced values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do you mean. Appreciate as always Gordon your great support and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

- Generate 6 random numbers between 0 and 1
- Normalize the values to be between 0 and 0.8 (or whatever)
- Add something back in if you don't want them to all start at 0

In SQL:

```
select x,
       max(x) over () - min(x) over () as starting_at_0,
       min(x) over () + 0.8 * (x - min(x) over ()) / (max(x) over () - min(x) over ()) as the_value_you_want
from (values (rand(checksum(newid()))),
             (rand(checksum(newid()))),
             (rand(checksum(newid()))),
             (rand(checksum(newid()))),
             (rand(checksum(newid()))),
             (rand(checksum(newid())))
      ) v(x);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=436797a4fe558b5c3e0490731c3ae19c) is a db<>fiddle.

Cast to `numeric(2, 1)`, if you want only one decimal point.

EDIT:

I tend to forget that this also works:

```
select x,
       max(x) over () - min(x) over () as starting_at_0,
       min(x) over () + 0.8 * (x - min(x) over ()) / (max(x) over () - min(x) over ()) as the_value_you_want
from (values (rand()),
             (rand()),
             (rand()),
             (rand()),
             (rand()),
             (rand())
      ) v(x);
```

(See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=78e89ddc307e7fc107e50a2237a51921).)

SQL Server treats `rand()` in a special way.  Each call to `rand()` is evaluated before the query is run.  So, `rand()` has the same value on multiple rows in the result set.  However, it has different values in different columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
with randvals(rval) as
( 
select rand()
union all
select rand()
union all
select rand()
union all
select rand()
union all
select rand()
union all
select rand()
),
arandvals(rval, xrval, mrval) as
(
select rval, max(rval) over() as xrval, min(rval) over() as mrval
from randvals
)
select cast(0.8 * rval / (xrval - mrval) as numeric(3,2))
from arandvals
```